# RStudioでファイルの保存ができません

Tags: windows-10, rstudio

画像のように、セーブのところだけ、灰色になって、選択できない状態です。長い間ずっとこのような状態で、色々調べましたが、何も分かりませんでした。原因や解決策などをご教授いただけたら幸いです。

[image: セーブのところだけ灰色になっています。]

Comment: RStudioの種類、バージョンを追記されると良いかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。バージョンを追記とは、インストールをし直すということでしょうか？それとも、他にアップデートの方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: お使いのRStudioの種類やバージョンが不明なので質問に追記してください、という意味です。